# ValueError: Shapes (2, 1) and () are incompatible

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-10, anaconda

I have to use Tensorflow 0.11 for [this code repo](https://github.com/lmb-freiburg/hand3d) and this is the error I get:

```
(py35) E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master>python run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 47, in <module>
    keypoints_scoremap_tf, keypoint_coord3d_tf = net.inference(image_tf, hand_side_tf, evaluation)
  File "E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master\net.py", line 37, in inference
    hand_mask = single_obj_scoremap(hand_scoremap)
  File "E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master\utils.py", line 246, in single_obj_scoremap
    max_loc = find_max_location(scoremap_fg)
  File "E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master\utils.py", line 228, in find_max_location
    xy_loc.append(tf.concat(0, [x_loc, y_loc]))
  File "C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1030, in concat
    ).assert_is_compatible_with(tensor_shape.scalar())
  File "C:\Users\mona6\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 735, in assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (2, 1) and () are incompatible

(py35) E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master>python
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Feb 22 2017, 21:28:42) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
'1.1.0'
>>>
```

Please suggest fixes.

The error seems to stem from the line `xy_loc.append(tf.concat(0, [x_loc, y_loc]))`

I wanted to make sure that I have the same exact subversion of Tensorflow so I did so but still get the above error.

```
(py35) E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master>pip install tensorflow==1.1.0rc0
Collecting tensorflow==1.1.0rc0
  Using cached tensorflow-1.1.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.2.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow==1.1.0rc0)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow 1.1.0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-1.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-1.1.0
Successfully installed tensorflow-1.1.0rc0
```

Comment: Please include a **[mcve]** *in the question*, not via a link.

Comment: @aryamccarthyI followed the instruction on the git repo, didn't change their code and when I ran it got the above error. I am not sure why you are voting to close it.

Comment: Because your linked code is not *minimal*.

Comment: I have shown exactly what needs to be run and what's the version of tensorflow I have which helps to easily reproduce the problem if you just download the repo!

Comment: I'm not questioning the reproducibility. I agree that it's complete and verifiable, but it's also a few hundred SLOCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the tensorflow 0.12 and the code worked perfectly with no change:
[image]

```
(py35) E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master>pip install tensorflow==1.2.0
Collecting tensorflow==1.2.0
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.2.0 (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.2.0

(py35) E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master>pip install tensorflow==0.12.1
Collecting tensorflow==0.12.1
  Downloading tensorflow-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl (13.7MB)
    100% |################################| 13.8MB 130kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.1.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==0.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in c:\users\mona6\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools->protobuf>=3.1.0->tensorflow==0.12.1)
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
  Found existing installation: tensorflow 1.1.0rc0
    Uninstalling tensorflow-1.1.0rc0:
      Successfully uninstalled tensorflow-1.1.0rc0
Successfully installed tensorflow-0.12.1

(py35) E:\opensource_codes\gesture_recognition\hand3d-master>python run.py
```