# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a 3 dimensional dataset of audio files where `X.shape` is `(329,20,85)`. I want to have a simpl bare-bones model running, so please don't nitpick and address only the issue at hand. Here is the code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, stateful=False, input_shape = (20,85,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(20))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
model.summary()
print("Train...")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=50, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

But then I had the error mentioned in the title:
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 3) are incompatible`

Here is the `model.summary()`

```
Model: "sequential_13"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_21 (LSTM)               (None, 20, 32)            15104     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_22 (LSTM)               (None, 20)                4240      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 63        
=================================================================
Total params: 19,407
Trainable params: 19,407
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train...
```

For this, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267737/valueerror-shapes-none-50-and-none-1-are-incompatible-in-tensorflow-and-c) post and updated Tensorflow to the latest version, but the issue persists. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901767/valueerror-shapes-2-1-and-are-incompatible) post is completely unrelated and highly unreliable.[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789274/tf-estimator-add-metrics-ends-in-shapes-none-12-and-none-are-incompatible) post although a bit relatable is unanswered for a while now.

**Update 1.0:**

I strongly think the problem has something to do with the final `Dense` layer where I pass nb_classes as 3, since I am classifying for 3 categories in `y`.

So I changed the `Dense` layer's `nb_classes` to 1, which ran the model and gives me this output, which I am positive is wrong.

```
Train...
9/9 [==============================] - 2s 177ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.1520 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 0.3418

<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f50f1dcebe0>
```

**Update 2.0:**

I one hot encoded the `y`s and resolved the shape issue. But now the above output with `<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f50f1dcebe0>` persists. Any help with this? Or should I post a new question for this? Thanks for all the help.

How should I proceed, or what should I be changing?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The first problem is with the LSTM input_shape. `input_shape = (20,85,1)`.

From the doc: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

LSTM layer expects **3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim).**

`model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))` - this suggets you're doing a multi-class classification.

So, you need your `y_train` and `y_test` have to be one-hot-encoded. That means they must have dimension `(number_of_samples, 3)`, where `3` denotes number of classes.

You need to apply `tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical` to them.

```
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 3)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 3)
```

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/to_categorical

`tf.keras.callbacks.History()` - this callback is automatically applied to every Keras model. The History object gets returned by the fit method of models.

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/History

Comment: Can you please check the second update in the question?

Comment: You mean this `<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f50f1dcebe0>`??

Comment: Yes that error. Its not even throwing it as an error just printing it as output.

Comment: It's a log, and not an error. You can change the log level of tensorflow or try this, `hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=50, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))`

Comment: Hello friends. How could I compare the y_predict against y_test using confusion matrix? I did this code y_pred = model.predict(testing_padded)
cmemb = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=y_test, predictions=y_pred, num_classes=3) but I couldnt get it. I just got this error InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions [0,2) of indices[shape=[4890,2,3]] must match dimensions [0,2) of updates[shape=[4890,3]]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

Check if the last Dense Layer(output) has same number of classes as the number of target classes in the training dataset. I made similar mistake while training the dataset and correcting it helped me.

Comment: Can I know how to change the Dense value?

Answer (score 8):

Another thing to check, is whether your labels are one-hot-coded, or integers only. See this post: https://www.kaggle.com/general/197993

> The error arose because 'categorical_crossentropy' works on one-hot encoded target, while 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' works on integer target.

Answer (score 2):

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

The `nb_classes` should be same as `y_train.shape[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the wrong variables used after One Hot Encoding for Classification problem.

```
trainY = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=9)
testY = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=9)
```

Modeling was done with y_train and y_test as below:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=50,
          batch_size = 128)
```

Correction did below and it worked as expected:

```
trainY = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=9)
testY = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=9)
```